# Unable to use DriveApp.getFileById(id).getLastUpdated();

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to know the latest updated date of a file at location "https://drive.google.com/open?id=XYZ". This address is present in A1 cell of my sheet.

But every time it throws this error: "You do not have permission to call DriveApp.getFileById. Required permissions: (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive) (line 3)."

I have made changes in appScript.jason file also.

This is the code that I have written in script editor and call from B1 cell:

```
function useThis(url){
    var id = getIdFromUrl(url);
  return DriveApp.getFileById(id).getLastUpdated();
}

function getIdFromUrl(url) { 
  return url.match(/[-\w]{25,}/); 
}
```

Also, my appscript.json looks like this:

```
{
  "timeZone": "Asia/Kolkata",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
  ]
}
```

Is there a way I can resolve this. Or any other easier way to get last updated date of a file in google drive?

Comment: I am using this as :" =useThis(A1) " in B1 cell

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution of your issue, how about adding ``https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly`` or ``https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`` to ``oauthScopes`` in ``appsscript.json`` and authorizing the scopes again?

Comment: I just tried it. Didn't work.

Comment: I apologize my comment was not useful for your situation.

Comment: Thank you for trying. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom functions are not applicable to your use case as they can only call services that do not require access to personal data. See  [GAS documentation on custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

> If your custom function throws the error message You do not have
>   permission to call X service., the service requires user authorization
>   and thus cannot be used in a custom function.

Comment: So, how is it possible for me to get the "last edit/update" date of a file and show it in a cell in my sheet?

Comment: @RobinDhiman You could create a custom menu option. Please read the docs I linked to - it's all in there.